# How to show google map on web page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to show a google map on the aspx page. 
      How to do that?

Also I want to show that it on some update panel of ajax control. Can update panel have the property that it refreshes in every 1 minute?

Thanks  & Regards,
Girish

Answer (score 2):

Read this article on:
[Integrating Google Maps into an ASP.NET page](http://blog.evonet.com.au/post/Integrating-Google-Maps-into-an-ASPNET-page.aspx)

For refreshing update panel, you can use the __doPostBack property. If event target of a __doPostBack() is an async trigger of an UpdatePanel, the ASP.NET AJAX framework fire a partial postback.

```
__doPostBack('yourupdatepanel', 'yourarguments');"
```

You can use an interval and then call __doPostBack.

For that, use the [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method:

```
setInterval("function()",intervaltime in milliseconds);
```

Comment: First link in answer is dead - *"This site can’t be reached / blog.evonet.com.au’s server DNS address could not be found"*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/).